# Calculadora java

Tags: java

Tengo este metodo para calcular operaciones y el problema es con las restas, un ejemplo si introduzco (50-5-5) el resultado me da 50 ya que lo que hace por orden es "5-5 = 0" y a continuacion "50-0".

Lo que hace es separar por operaciones y sobre esas mismas calcular con el propio metodo, el problema es que creo que automaticamente me realiza la operacion mas cercana a la ultima aparicion del signo -, es decir si primero me hiciera (50 -5) Y al resultado le volviera a restar el resto de la cadena estaria solucionado pero no consigo hacerlo.

Adjunto codigo:

```
private Double operar(String op) {

        int pos = op.indexOf('+') ;

        if (pos != -1 && !op.contains("%")) {

            return operar(op.substring(0,pos)) + operar(op.substring(pos+1)); 

        } else  {

            pos = op.indexOf('-') ;

            if (pos != -1 && !op.contains("%")) {

                return operar(op.substring(0,pos)) - operar(op.substring(pos+1)); 

            } else  {

                pos = op.indexOf('*') ;

                if (pos != -1) {

                    return operar(op.substring(0,pos)) * operar(op.substring(pos+1)); 

                } else  {

                    pos = op.indexOf('/');

                    if (pos != -1) {

                        return operar(op.substring(0,pos)) / operar(op.substring(pos+1)); 

                    } else {

                        pos = op.indexOf('√');

                        if (pos != -1) {

                            return Math.sqrt(operar(op.substring(pos+1)));

                        } else {

                            int pos1;
                            pos = op.indexOf('%');

                            double resultado;

                            if (pos != -1) {

                                if (op.contains("-")) {

                                    pos1 = op.indexOf('-');

                                    resultado = Double.parseDouble((op.substring(0, pos1))) * ( Double.parseDouble(op.substring(pos1+1, pos)) /100);

                                    return resultado=Double.parseDouble((op.substring(0, pos1))) - resultado; 

                                } else if (op.contains("+")) {

                                    pos1 = op.indexOf('+');
                                    
                                    resultado = Double.parseDouble((op.substring(0, pos1))) * ( Double.parseDouble(op.substring(pos1+1, pos)) /100);

                                    return resultado=Double.parseDouble((op.substring(0, pos1))) + resultado; 

                                } else {
                                    
                                    return  resultado = Double.parseDouble((op.substring(0, pos))) * ( Double.parseDouble(op.substring(pos+1)) /100);

                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }

        return Double.parseDouble(op);
    }
```

Agradeceria si me echais una mano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código resulta complicado de leer con tantos if anidados y llamadas recursivas, el error debe estar en alguno de los if.
Entiendo que con esa función pretendes calcular el total pasándole un String, siendo los operandos la suma y la resta. Algo como esto:

```
public static Double operar(String op) {

    String operadores[] = op.split("[0-9]+");
    String operandos[] = op.split("[+-]");

    double resultado = Double.parseDouble(operandos[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < operadores.length; i++) {
        switch (operadores[i]) {
        case "+":
            resultado += Double.parseDouble(operandos[i]);
            break;
        case "-":
            resultado -= Double.parseDouble(operandos[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Espero que ese código te pueda servir ! `:)`